# Query Dashboard Field

Tags: dashboard

I'm trying to clean up dashboards without going through the hundreds of dashboards I have. When I query "Select ID, dashboardResultRefreshedDate from Dashboard" I don't see any value for the dashboardResultRefreshedDate field. I discovered this field under the Metadata API Developer Guide (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_dashboard.htm), but I thought this field would be queryable since I didn't get an error when running the query. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know anything about Dashboards, but I just did your query quickly in Developer Console.  We have 54 Dashboard records and `dashboardResultRefreshedDate` is empty for all of them.

Comment: There is an idea on idea exchange for this feature. Also surprisingly this field not mention in the object reference. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.226.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_dashboard.htm

Comment: I also tried my query in the developer console and the field was empty. Thank you for verifying this for me because I was trying in a non-profit's org and I wanted to make sure it wasn't some odd rule in non-profit orgs.

Does anyone know if this field can be accessed via SF's API?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Known Issue related to this https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000j5kQaAAI/dashboard-objects-fields-dashboardresultrefresheddate-and-dashboardresultrunninguser-is-empty-for-all-dashboards

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.